Why it cant create DEPFILE when compiling qt6 locally?
When I compile qt6, my compiler tells me that it is unable to create DEPFILE, it seems related to a qsb file, but I am not familiar with qt so I can give more information. Cmake log is as below.
[ 52%] Built target qsb
[ 52%] Generating prl file for target Multimedia
[ 52%] Generating pc file for target Qt6::Multimedia
[ 52%] Generating .qsb/shaders/abgr_linear.frag.qsb
[ 52%] Generating .qsb/shaders/argb.frag.qsb
[ 52%] Generating .qsb/shaders/abgr.frag.qsb
[ 52%] Generating .qsb/shaders/argb_linear.frag.qsb
Unable to create DEPFILE: '/home/arrebolgalaxy/qt6/qt6-build/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/abgr_linear.frag.qsb.d'
[ 52%] Generating .qsb/shaders/ayuv.frag.qsb
Unable to create DEPFILE: '/home/arrebolgalaxy/qt6/qt6-build/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/argb.frag.qsb.d'
[ 52%] Generating .qsb/shaders/bgra_linear.frag.qsb
Unable to create DEPFILE: '/home/arrebolgalaxy/qt6/qt6-build/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/abgr.frag.qsb.d'
[ 52%] Generating .qsb/shaders/bgra.frag.qsb
[ 53%] Generating .qsb/shaders/externalsampler_linear.frag.qsb@glsl,100es,shaders/externalsampler_gles_linear.frag.qsb
[ 52%] Generating .qsb/shaders/ayuv_linear.frag.qsb
gmake[2]: *** [qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/CMakeFiles/Multimedia.dir/build.make:276：qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/abgr_linear.frag.qsb] 错误 1
gmake[2]: *** 正在等待未完成的任务....
gmake[2]: *** [qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/CMakeFiles/Multimedia.dir/build.make:155：qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/abgr.frag.qsb] 错误 1
gmake[2]: *** [qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/CMakeFiles/Multimedia.dir/build.make:161：qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/argb.frag.qsb] 错误 1
[ 53%] Generating .qsb/shaders/imc2.frag.qsb
Unable to create DEPFILE: '/home/arrebolgalaxy/qt6/qt6-build/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/argb_linear.frag.qsb.d'[ 52%] Generating .qsb/shaders/externalsampler.frag.qsb
[ 52%] Generating .qsb/shaders/externalsampler.vert.qsb

gmake[2]: *** [qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/CMakeFiles/Multimedia.dir/build.make:282：qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/argb_linear.frag.qsb] 错误 1
Unable to create DEPFILE: '/home/arrebolgalaxy/qt6/qt6-build/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/ayuv.frag.qsb.d'Unable to create DEPFILE: '/home/arrebolgalaxy/qt6/qt6-build/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/ayuv_linear.frag.qsb.d'

gmake[2]: *** [qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/CMakeFiles/Multimedia.dir/build.make:167：qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/ayuv.frag.qsb] 错误 1
gmake[2]: *** [qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/CMakeFiles/Multimedia.dir/build.make:288：qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/ayuv_linear.frag.qsb] 错误 1
Unable to create DEPFILE: '/home/arrebolgalaxy/qt6/qt6-build/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/bgra_linear.frag.qsb.d'
gmake[2]: *** [qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/CMakeFiles/Multimedia.dir/build.make:294：qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/bgra_linear.frag.qsb] 错误 1
Unable to create DEPFILE: '/home/arrebolgalaxy/qt6/qt6-build/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/bgra.frag.qsb.d'
Unable to create DEPFILE: '/home/arrebolgalaxy/qt6/qt6-build/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/externalsampler.vert.qsb.d'
gmake[2]: *** [qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/CMakeFiles/Multimedia.dir/build.make:173：qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/bgra.frag.qsb] 错误 1
gmake[2]: *** [qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/CMakeFiles/Multimedia.dir/build.make:186：qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/externalsampler.vert.qsb] 错误 1
Unable to create DEPFILE: '/home/arrebolgalaxy/qt6/qt6-build/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/externalsampler.frag.qsb.d'
[ 53%] Built target QWaylandWlShellIntegrationPlugin
gmake[2]: *** [qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/CMakeFiles/Multimedia.dir/build.make:179：qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/externalsampler.frag.qsb] 错误 1
Unable to create DEPFILE: '/home/arrebolgalaxy/qt6/qt6-build/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/imc2.frag.qsb.d'
gmake[2]: *** [qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/CMakeFiles/Multimedia.dir/build.make:192：qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/imc2.frag.qsb] 错误 1
Unable to create DEPFILE: '/home/arrebolgalaxy/qt6/qt6-build/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/externalsampler_linear.frag.qsb@glsl,100es,shaders/externalsampler_gles_linear.frag.qsb.d'
gmake[2]: *** [qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/CMakeFiles/Multimedia.dir/build.make:300：qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/externalsampler_linear.frag.qsb@glsl,100es,shaders/externalsampler_gles_linear.frag.qsb] 错误 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:70461：qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/CMakeFiles/Multimedia.dir/all] 错误 2
gmake[1]: *** 正在等待未完成的任务....

I use Chinese as system language, '错误' means 'error', '正在等待未完成的任务' means 'pending for unfinished task'. And it is a pity that the QT has no official open source installer any more :(
Thank you for your help!
$ mkdir qt6-build
$ cd qt6-build
$ ../qt6/configure -prefix /path/to/install
$ cmake --build . --parallel 4
$ cmake --install .

It happens when I run the cmake build command, and I am sure that I already have essential build tools installed. I run the command both in normal user + sudo and root user, none of them work and the same error occurs.

I got the same error (on macOS). Don't know why

mkdir -p /home/arrebolgalaxy/qt6/qt6-build/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/.qsb/shaders/

create this path manully

and compile again

You can (and should) [edit] your answer if you want to update it. Comments aren't guaranteed to be here forever.
